# How to make window appear in taskbar?

Tags: c#, .net, taskbar

A window is not showing in the task bar, only in the system tray. How can I make it show up in the taskbar as well?

I tried the following code, but it had no effect:

```
int windowStyle = GetWindowLong(pMainWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(pMainWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, windowStyle & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
```

And, this is NOT my form! I'm getting the handle from Process.GetProcessesByName and I don't know how to access properties of the Form class:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("somename");
someProcess = processes[0];

pMainWindow = someProcess.MainWindowHandle;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to do the trick. If you hide & reshow the window after calling SetWindowLong it then shows in the taskbar.

I'm struggling to find a way to remove it from the taskbar once the window is minimized...

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]                
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

private const int SW_HIDE = 0x00;
private const int SW_SHOW = 0x05;

private const int WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x40000;
private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -0x14;

private void ShowWindowInTaskbar(IntPtr pMainWindow)
{                       
    SetWindowLong(pMainWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);

    ShowWindow(pMainWindow, SW_HIDE);
    ShowWindow(pMainWindow, SW_SHOW);      
}
```

Comment: Cool no problem. If you are maximizing the window from the system tray AKA notify icon, just bear in mind that when the user minimizes the window they will *expect it* to be removed from the taskbar. As I said in my answer, I couldn't get that bit to work...

Comment: I think this is sort of wrong, e.g. assuming the window is a top-most one, this would clear the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` flag. You would also need to use `GetWindowLong` and a `|`.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` instead of `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`.  From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(VS.85).aspx):

`WS_EX_APPWINDOW`: Forces a top-level window onto the taskbar when the window is visible.

`WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`: ...A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the dialog that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB...

Comment: thank you! tried both SetWindowLong(pMainWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, windowStyle & WS_EX_APPWINDOW); and SetWindowLong(pMainWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, windowStyle & WS_EX_APPWINDOW); but without any result. while googling i've found "just setting the extended window style itself wasn't enough -- it was only able to work correctly upon initialization of the window", maybe it is a problem

Comment: ...a solution there was to make app window a parent of the window, which we want to edit. but I have no window in my app, it's a dll!

Answer (score 0):

Set the .ShowInTaskbar property of the form to true.

Comment: sorry, I haven't given you all the information. this is not my form

Answer (score -1):

Can you cast the object returned Process.GetProcessesByName() as a form, then set its .ShowInTaskbar property?

Comment: something like...

Object O = new Object();
O = Process.GetProcessesByName();
((Form)O).ShowInTaskBar = true;